# Issue in GSM for Straight Talk and MMS.

Tags: mms, apn, gsm

I just purchased a **GSM** unlocked Android phone.

And called into Straight Talk to get the new `APN` setting.

But, the settings they gave me would not allow me to receive **MMS**.

The web and testing works fine.

Please help me on which settings to use?

**NOTE:**

Someone told me to re-configure my phone, will this help?

Comment: What service is your straight talk under? Your APN settings have to match the network that you join.

Try this form:
http://www.straighttalk.com/wps/portal/home/support/apn/!ut/p/b1/04_SjzQztzA3MDQ0N9KP0I_KSyzLTE8syczPS8wB8aPM4l0MvHyNAx09jIKM3FwNPN3cjAx8PYMM3N0N9HOjHBUBlTx7Ew!!/

Answer (score -1):

Try with these settings: http://apn.gishan.net/settings/os_12_11_android_4.4kitkat_internet_and_mms_settings_for_straight_talk.php

Should work. Sorry. Site does not allow me to copy the settings. 
How ever if you cannot receive MMS that should be a data problem. Please check you can access data properly. MMS APN is only for sending MMS. Do you receive MMS notification at least?

Comment: When that link stops working, this answer has no value. Please don't make future readers go to some other site to get the information they need.